# Sumation of Multiple Field Cumulative Sum

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, numeric-data

I have a | delimited file with multiple fields `(Field_1 to Field_10)`, and some of the fields have dollar amounts.

I would like to get the cumulative sum of say `Field_1 ($ amount), Field_5 ($ amount), Field_6 ($ amount)`, and produce an output which is equal to `SUM(Field_1)+SUM(Field_5)+SUM(Field_6)`.

Comment: What have you tried?  How did it not work?  Provide example input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Given a sample input file of:

```
$1.50|field 2|field 3|field 4|$3.50|$42|field 7|field 8|field 9|field 10
$2.30|field 2|field 3|field 4|$4.50|$4200|field 7|field 8|field 9|field 10
```

Then this awk program will sum fields 1, 5, and 6, then print the total at the end:

```
awk -F '|' '{sum += substr($1, 2) + substr($5, 2) + substr($6, 2)} END { printf "$%.2f\n", sum }' input
```